# VBA VLookup If Match MsgBox Else Continue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template that is being used to look up a list of accounts. Its kind of like a workflow tool, where tab 1 shows a list of active accounts. Tab 2 is where data formatting takes place and tab 3 is where the completed accounts are listed. This is being used by multiple people. So as they work through the list I wanted to apply some error handling that applies a vlookup to the account the user has selected just to see if its already in the completed tab by another user.

So essentially I really want it to Vlookup against the completed list. If a match then msgbox to say "This account has already been completed", else carry on formatting the data.

The code I was trying to use was:

```
Set WsInput = Sheets("Account Search")
Set PolLookup = WsInput.Range("U3")
Set PolRange = Sheets("Completed Accounts").Range("B5:B15000")

With WsInput
    .Range("U3").Value = Application.VLookup(PolLookup, PolRange, 1, False)
        If IsError(.Range("U3").Value) Then

*Format Data

Else
    MsgBox "This account has already been completed", vbExclamation
    Sheets("Completed Accounts").Select
    Exit Sub

End If

End With
```

However I can't seem to get it to work. If I put a matching account number in it goes to the msgbox, which is what I want, but if I put a new number in, it also goes to the msgbox?

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `but if I put a new number in, it also goes to the msgbox` - and what appears in U3 in that case?

Comment: Hi GSerg, sorry should have mention U3 is the cell being used to enter the account number that the user is working in. So they copy or type it from the list in tab one into cell U3 in tab 2. Then on pressing a formatting button I want this vlookup code to kick in to provide some error handling.

Comment: You are saving the result of `vlookup` in U3. So what appears there when you press the button?

Comment: Thanks GSerg, do you know if VBA can just hold it in memory somewhere and not actually paste it into cell U3. I don't really need to display it anywhere just use it for the look up

Comment: Its a bit rough and ready, but I think I've got it to work. I couldn't work out how to hold the value of U3 in VBA's memory so I've used a cell at the end of the tab to hold the value and check

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub Check()

    Dim sPol As String, rngPol As Range
    sPol = Sheets("Account Search").Range("U3").Value
    Set rngPol = Sheets("Completed Accounts").Range("B5:B15000")

    If IsError(Application.VLookup(sPol, rngPol, 1, False)) Then
   
        ' do something
        MsgBox sPol & " not completed"

    Else
        MsgBox "Account " & sPol & " has already been completed", vbExclamation
        Sheets("Completed Accounts").Select
        Exit Sub
   End If

End Sub
```